# How to solve unreachable code eclipse... if get exception the " hai " statement will not execute

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following code: my new code here

```
try{
   int a=10, b=0;
   if(a<b) {
      throw new Exception("false");
   }
   String n = "30.0";
   float ff = (float) 0.0;
   if (Float.parseFloat(n) < ff) {
       throw new Exception("big");
   } else {
       throw new Exception("add");
   }
   System.out.println("hai"); //unreachable code
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Could someone please help me understand why the last statement is unreachable and how to solve this?

Comment: Are you asking why is that code unreachable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You throw an exception, therefore you will never reach the print

Answer (score 2):

What's important to understand here is that when you throw an exception, **the rest of the code is skipped**. In this case this means that `System.out.println("hai");` is always skipped, since you throw an exception in both branches of the if-statement. If it's always skipped, it's unreachable!

Here's an illustration:

```
try {
   int a=10, b=0;
   if(a<b) {
      throw new Exception("false");
   }
   String n = "30.0";
   float ff = (float) 0.0;
   if (Float.parseFloat(n) < ff) {
       throw new Exception("big");  ----------------------.
   } else {                                               |
       throw new Exception("add");  ------------------.   |
   }                                                  |   |
   System.out.println("hai"); //unreachable code      |   |
} catch(Exception e){                                 |   |
    /* execution continues here */   <----------------+---'
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

If you want the `"hai"` to be reachable, you'll have to move it to a place where it's not always skipped. For instance to below the catch block:

```
try {
   int a=10, b=0;
   if(a<b) {
      throw new Exception("false");
   }
   String n = "30.0";
   float ff = (float) 0.0;
   if (Float.parseFloat(n) < ff) {
       throw new Exception("big");
   } else {
       throw new Exception("add");
   }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
System.out.println("hai"); // reachable!
```

Comment: But if i will get exception .. then "Hai" statement is not execute.. thats is my concept..

Comment: Right. This is because the exception makes the code "terminate" before reaching the "Hai" line. The ASCII arrow in my answer indivates the control flow.

Comment: could you please explain me...i am not understood.. i am new for java developing..

Comment: If you're stuck on something particular, and have a specific follow-up question, feel free to write it here.

Comment: First of all: It's *impossible* to force the compiler to accept this program. As it stands it's simply not valid Java code. So, to "solve" the issue (i.e. make sure `"Hai"` is printed) you can wrap the `throw`-code in a `try`/`catch` block as I've shown in the second code snippet in my answer. (If this doesn't solve your issue in a desirable way, then please clarify how you want the program to work.)

Comment: @Arjun, I've clarified my answer a bit. Let me know if it is easier to understand now.

Comment: @Arjun, if it answers your question, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

You are `throwing` the `Exeption`, so method execution will stop there itself and return from that point.

To solve you cab use `try-catch to catch the Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code **always** throws one exception or the other, which is why the code following is never reached.

> how to solve this issues

Don't throw an exception in one of your cases, or don't have code after code that always throws exceptions.